# Can't Add Reference to Visual C# Console App in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have created a Visual C# Console App and I am trying to add reference to resolve an error. Since I am new to the IDE and I am looking for some help on how to add the Reference via the editor. I am trying to connect to Azure Storage via this app.

Attaching the screen shot.

I used the general resolution saying

1. In Solution Explorer, double-click the My Project node for the
   project.
2. In the Project Designer, click the References tab.

But I am not seeing the References tab to add Reference.

[image]

Comment: Right-click on your project (BlobEx.csproj)

Comment: If the project is the part of your solution, you should be able to add project reference. If still you are not able to do this, then you may verify if the Target framework is same for your project and the reference that you are trying to add.

Go to your project -> Right click on project -> properties -> Application Tab (Target frame work)

Answer (score 12):

Thanks for help. First place I was supposed to create a 'Console App (.Net Framework' instead I mistakenly chose Console App (.NET Core). Now I am ble to see the Refrences.
Thanks for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First of all switch the Solution Explorer view by clicking button in the header as shown in the below image:

[image]

After that you will find the "References" node in the tree. Right click and then choose **Add Reference**

[image]

**References:**
[Managing references in a project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx)
[How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use .NET Core (.NET) instead of .NET Framework, just install this package in PM:

`PM> Install-Package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager -Version <YourCompatibleVersion>`